# apk return DNS lookup error on docker build

Tags: docker, dns

When run any `apk add ...` command while `docker build ...` I get `DNS lookup error`:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main: DNS lookup error
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community: DNS lookup error
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11):

It seems that my Dokcer inside of `docker-machine` had troubles resolving DNS.

I added this file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` into machine to make everything work correctly:

```json
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "192.168.0.1"]
}
```

Also you may use `docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 ...` if you just run container.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to restart docker using "sudo service docker restart"

Comment: For minikube docker make sure you are updating in minikube server (`ssh minikube`) and restarting minikube docker (`sudo service docker restart`)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix it

edit `/etc/init.d/docker`

Update the following property

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns x.x.x.x"
```

Restart docker service

```
sudo service docker restart
```